# Razor displays literal @Model.title instead of value, depending on which tab is active in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nancy, owin

I'm following the new [Katana article from MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451439.aspx). Instead of the model's title, the page literally shows this:

> @Model.title

If I put a breakpoint in my HomeModule and step through it, then the page correctly shows this:

> We've got issues...

This is the HomeModule:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ =>
        {
            var model = new { title = "We've got issues..." };
            return View["home", model];
        };
    }
}
```

Why would setting a breakpoint, and therefore altering the timing, cause the page to display the model's title correctly? Is the HTML being rendered too quickly? I'm not sure how that could be because isn't the HomeModule what decides what HTML is even returned?

Note: When putting a breakpoint in HomeModule, it gets hit twice. Not sure why. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Here is the beginning of Home.html. The last line shows the @Model.title portion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <title>@Model.title</title>
```

**Edit**

So this is weird. In VS 2013, when I click to run the app, I get the correct results if HomeModule is the active tab. If Home.html is the active tab, I get the literal @Model.title.

Comment: Is it home.html - not home.cshtml?

Comment: Correct, it's `Home.html`.

Comment: have you tried renaming to .cshtml?

Comment: I just tried that. I don't think you can use `.cshtml` with Nancy: `Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'home.cshtml'
Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm`

Comment: You can if you've installed the razor engine using Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor nuget

Comment: I just referenced Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor and I get the same problem, kind of. If HomeModule is the active tab in VS, and I run/debug the app, it works. If Home.cshtml is the active tab, I get `404 - NotFound`.

Comment: What is the url displayed while you run the app when html file is the active tab?

Comment: So that's interesting. When the HTML file is the active tab, the URL is this: `http://localhost:52371/Views/Home.html`. When HomeModule is the active tab, it's this: `http://localhost:52371`.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Nancy, this is Visual Studio trying to be "helpful" by assuming you want to view that page in your browser, and assuming it's a normal website.. neither of which are actually helpful.

Comment: @StevenRobbins If that's the case, then you've answered my question. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Nancy, this is Visual Studio trying to be "helpful" by assuming you want to view that page in your browser, and assuming it's a normal website.. neither of which are actually helpful.

I agree it's annoying as hell, but it's a Visual Studio "feature" - maybe try digging in tools/options and see if there's any way to switch it off?

**Edit from Bob Horn - I found the setting**

In the properties of the project, on the web tab, Current Page *was* selected. After I changed that setting to Start URL, and used the same URL specified in the Project URL textbox, running the app worked as expected.

[image]